# how to cancel python schedule

Tags: python

I have a repeated python schedule task as following,which need to run getMyStock() every 3 minutes in startMonitor():

```
from stocktrace.util import settings
import time, os, sys, sched
schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def periodic(scheduler, interval, action, actionargs=()):
  scheduler.enter(interval, 1, periodic,
                  (scheduler, interval, action, actionargs))
  action(*actionargs)


def startMonitor():    
    from stocktrace.parse.sinaparser import getMyStock       

    periodic(schedule, settings.POLLING_INTERVAL, getMyStock)
    schedule.run( )
```

The questions are:

1.how could i cancel or stop the schedule when some user event comes?

2.Is there any other python module for better repeated scheduling?Just like java quartz?

Comment: Where is that `stocktrace` package from?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Q1: `scheduler.enter` returns the event object that is scheduled, so keep a handle on that and you can `cancel` it:

```
from stocktrace.util import settings
from stocktrace.parse.sinaparser import getMyStock   
import time, os, sys, sched

class Monitor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        self.interval = settings.POLLING_INTERVAL
        self._running = False

    def periodic(self, action, actionargs=()):
        if self._running:
            self.event = self.scheduler.enter(self.interval, 1, self.periodic, (action, actionargs))
            action(*actionargs)

    def start(self):
        self._running = True
        self.periodic(getMyStock)
        self.schedule.run( )

    def stop(self):
        self._running = False
        if self.schedule and self.event:
            self.schedule.cancel(self.event)
```

I've moved your code into a class to make referring to the event more convenient.

Q2 is outside of the scope of this site.

Comment: The nasty thing, though, is that cancelling it from another thread is subject to a *race condition*, where the event could fire before it is cancelled, leading to an old event being cancelled (and the event subsequently continuing to run). I think you may need both a flag (or lock) and the `cancel` call to guarantee cancellation.

Comment: @Matthew I run this script in win32 service, when i start service will run startMonitor(),when stop the service,it will call stop() method, but it seems blocked and fail to stop the win32 service.

Comment: @nneonneo: thanks for pointing that out, I've updated to include a flag.

Comment: @Grace: I've modified the code slightly to take nneonneo's comments into account, hopefully that'll help.

Comment: @Matthew: according to your latest update,it does work now.Except the periodic method part (self.scheduler, self.interval, action, actionargs) should only take two parameters as (action,actionargs).Thanks for your great help.

Comment: If I set `blocking=False` when calling the `self.schedule.run()` method my periodical action is being executed only once. Do you know why is that?

Comment: @NutCracker please post this as a question instead

Answer (score 2):

For cancelling a scheduled action

`scheduler.cancel(event)`

Removes the event from the queue. If event is not an event currently in the queue, this method will raise a ValueError [Doc here](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html)

`event` is a Return value of `scheduler.enter` function which may be used for later cancellation of the event

Comment: but for my case how could i get the event?My schedule is a periodical one.