# How to start and stop a periodic background task?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

This application needs to be able to start and stop a periodic heartbeat message before and after various other user initiated tasks. Using @Matthew's [Monitor class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12907698/398460) as an example, there is no periodic `Heartbeat message sent` printed when starting the message or indication that the message is being sent. There is also no error message indicating why the periodic task has not started - just the print messages for opStartHeartbeat and opStopHeartbeat. What is missing?

```
def opHeartbeat():
    ...
    zocket.send(opMsg)
    print "Heartbeat message sent"

class HeartbeatClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        self._running = False

    def periodic(self, action, actionargs=()):
        if self._running:
            self.event = self.schedule.enter(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL, 1, self.periodic, (action, actionargs))
            action(*actionargs)

    def start(self):
        self._running = True
        self.periodic(opHeartbeat)
        self.schedule.run()

    def stop(self):
        self._running = False
        if self.schedule and self.event:
            self.schedule.cancel(self.event)

heartbeat = HeartbeatClass()

def opStartHeartbeat():
    global HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL
    HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = raw_input('Enter Heartbeat period: ')
    heartbeat.start()

def opStopHeartbeat():
    heartbeat.stop()
    print "   Heartbeat stopped"

def opMenuChoice(option):
   ...
   elif (option == 31):
      opStartHeartbeat()
   elif (option == 32):
      opStopHeartbeat()
   return

while (option != 99):
   option = raw_input('Enter menu option: ')
   opMenuChoice(option)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to call the methods:

```
def opStartHeartbeat():
    global HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL
    HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = raw_input('Enter Heartbeat period: ')
    heartbeat.start()  # Round brackets call the method

def opStopHeartbeat():
    heartbeat.stop()
    print "   Heartbeat stopped"
```