# How to make a scheduled task that does not block?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

This modification to [Monitor class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907581/how-to-cancel-python-schedule/12907698#12907698) needs to be able to start and stop a periodic message before and after other user initiated tasks. It is currently able to start the periodic message but then blocks, not allowing the user to start another task or gracefully stop itself (`heartbeat.stop()`). Is there a way to fix this so that `heartbeat.start()` does not block?

```
def opHeartbeat():
    ...
    zocket.send(opMsg)

class HeartbeatClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        self._running = False

    def periodic(self, action, actionargs=()):
        if self._running:
            self.event = self.schedule.enter(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL, 1, self.periodic, (action, actionargs))
            action(*actionargs)

    def start(self):
        self._running = True
        self.periodic(opHeartbeat)
        self.schedule.run()

    def stop(self):
        self._running = False
        if self.schedule and self.event:
            self.schedule.cancel(self.event)

heartbeat = HeartbeatClass()

def opStartHeartbeat():
    print "   Enter Heartbeat period in seconds or <enter> for 5s"
    global HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL
    HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = raw_input('   Enter Heartbeat period: ')
    if HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL == (""):
        HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = 5
    heartbeat.start()

def opStopHeartbeat():
    heartbeat.stop()

def opMenuChoice(option):
   ...
   elif (option == 31):
      opStartHeartbeat()
   elif (option == 32):
      opStopHeartbeat()
   ...

option = 0
GObject.threads_init()
while (option != 99):
   option = raw_input('Enter menu option: ')
   opMenuChoice(option)
```

Comment: Why not use `apschedule` lib? You can use `BackgroundScheduler`.

Comment: @Sraw : Yes. This works perfectly. If you move your comment to an answer I'll mark it as accepted.