# How to cancel scheduled job once it's completed -Python

Tags: python, schedule

```
import schedule
import time
def test():
    print("Stopped")
    # I tried these two commands below it's not helping or maybe I am doing it wrong.
    # schedule.cancel_job(test)
    # schedule.clear()
schedule.every().day.at("21:43").do(test)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want to cancel job once it's completed, here I know it's not completed because I have used ***day*** so it runs each day, but I just want to cancel this job once it's performed or if is there any other way to do same thing it will be good and it must be easy like schedule.
Technically I have created a python bot there are multiple scheduled tasks I want to implement this idea there.
Plus I am not understanding this if it relates to my query:

[how to cancel python schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907581/how-to-cancel-python-schedule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you only want the scheduled task to run once.

If so, this is an FAQ on the schedule webpage and it gives the following suggestion

```
def job_that_executes_once():
    # Do some work ...
    return schedule.CancelJob

schedule.every().day.at('22:30').do(job_that_executes_once)
```

See https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-run-a-job-only-once

A better way to exit the program once all the jobs have completed or been cancelled is as follows

```
import schedule
import time

def test():
    print("Running")
    return schedule.CancelJob

schedule.every().minute.do(test)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    if not schedule.jobs:
        break
    time.sleep(1)

print("I'm done")
```

This code will break out of the while loop when there are no more jobs in schedules list.

Comment: Hey, I used the CancelJob but it is not working. I am using aioschedule.

Comment: @AkrashNadeem Perhaps you can raise a new question for this. I'm not familiar with aioschedule.

Comment: I have fixed that problem by canceling it manually but for now I need to change the timezone of the aioschedule. if you can tell

Answer (score 2):

If you only want it to run once, add the line `return schedule.CancelJob` to the end of the function:

```
import schedule
import time
def test():
    print("Stopped")
    return schedule.CancelJob
schedule.every().day.at("21:43").do(test)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you want to break the loop:

```
import schedule
import time
running = True
def test():
    global running
    running = False
    print("Stopped")
    return schedule.CancelJob
schedule.every().day.at("21:43").do(test)
while running:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

[Here are the relevant docs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-run-a-job-only-once)

Answer (score 0):

The python `schedule` library seems to be for periodic jobs. What you are describing is more of a time triggered job. You'd better check time in your `while True` loop.

By the way, if you tag your job, you can use the schedule.cancel_job(tag) to cancel your job.