# python schedule module - not executing

Tags: python, schedule

Accoring to the documentation the following sample code should execute once, but it does not when including var currentTime  , can you tell me how to pass the var to the schedule process properly

```
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime

currentTime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
def job_that_executes_once():
# Do some work that only needs to happen once...
    print ('Only Once')
    return schedule.CancelJob
schedule.every().day.at('22:30').do(job_that_executes_once)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('Not executed')
```

Comment: Tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238891/how-to-cancel-scheduled-job-once-its-completed-python ? It involves adding a loop variable and breaking from it after the task is completed.

Comment: The way you have it, you can access the variable as a global without a problem.  What isn't working?

Comment: @TimRoberts if you change the line schedule.every().day.at('22:30').do(job_that_executes_once) to schedule.every().day.at(currentTime ).do(job_that_executes_once), then the function job_that_executes_once, will be executed.